# Getting all the combinations of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a Numpy array like `X=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`
I want to put all of the combinations of these numbers into an array.

How would I go about getting an array with each row being a combination of X and the length is how ever many combinations there are?

Comment: Combinations or permutations?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements ?

Comment: That question talks about doing it with lists. My question is different, I specifically want to do it with Numpy arrays and in such a way that it returns an array as described in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your question you are actually looking for permutations:

```py
from itertools import permutations

import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

perm_array = np.asarray([p for p in permutations(x)])
print(perm_array.shape)
# prints(120, 5)
```

Each row of `perm_array` will contain a permutation of your input.

Watch out that the number of permutations [grows extremely quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)!

Answer (score 0):

Available in itertools:

```py
from itertools import combinations
X=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
X_combinations = {} # dictionary key r: combinations of rank r. 
for r in range(len(X) + 1): 
  X_combinations[r] = list(combinations(X, r))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(X_combinations)
```

output:

```py
{0: [()],
 1: [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)],
 2: [(1, 2),
     (1, 3),
     (1, 4),
     (1, 5),
     (2, 3),
     (2, 4),
     (2, 5),
     (3, 4),
     (3, 5),
     (4, 5)],
 3: [(1, 2, 3),
     (1, 2, 4),
     (1, 2, 5),
     (1, 3, 4),
     (1, 3, 5),
     (1, 4, 5),
     (2, 3, 4),
     (2, 3, 5),
     (2, 4, 5),
     (3, 4, 5)],
 4: [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5)],
 5: [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]}
```